# assign @categories not available in eex template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have two models, Product and Category. I was able to add/edit a product with the chosen category, but now after I set up Arc I face error: assign @categories not available in eex template, when I try to add or edit a product. Does anyone have an idea what I could have done wrong or I am missing in my code? I am using Phoenix 1.4.

My schemas:

```
  schema "products" do
    field :avdate, :date
    field :description, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :price, :float
    field :prodimg, ShopifyWeb.DisplayImage.Type
    field :quantity, :integer
    field :subcategory, :integer
    belongs_to :category, Shopify.Departments.Category
    has_many :comments, Shopify.Reviews.Comment
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(product, attrs) do
    product
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :quantity, :price, :subcategory, :description, :avdate, :category_id])
    |> cast_attachments(attrs, [:prodimg])
    |> validate_required([:name, :quantity, :price, :subcategory, :description, :avdate, :category_id])

  end

  schema "categories" do
    field :name, :string
    field :subcategory, :string
    has_many :products, Shopify.Inventory.Product
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(category, attrs) do
    category
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :subcategory])
    |> validate_required([:name, :subcategory])
  end
```

New/Edit in product controller:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Inventory.change_product(%Product{})
    categories = Repo.all(Category) |> Enum.map(&{&1.name, &1.id})
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, categories: categories)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"product" => product_params}) do
    case Inventory.create_product(product_params) do
      {:ok, product} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Product created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.product_path(conn, :show, product))

      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    product = Inventory.get_product!(id)

    comment_changeset = Reviews.change_comment(%Comment{})
    render(conn, "show.html", product: product, comment_changeset: comment_changeset)
  end

  def edit(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    product = Inventory.get_product!(id)
    changeset = Inventory.change_product(product)
    categories = Repo.all(Category) |> Enum.map(&{&1.name, &1.id})
    render(conn, "edit.html", product: product,  changeset: changeset, categories: categories)
  end

  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "product" => product_params}) do
    product = Inventory.get_product!(id)

    case Inventory.update_product(product, product_params) do
      {:ok, product} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Product updated successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.product_path(conn, :show, product))

      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        render(conn, "edit.html", product: product, changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

My product form:

```
 <%= form_for @changeset, @action, [multipart: true], fn f -> %>
      <%= if @changeset.action do %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= label f, :name %>
      <%= text_input f, :name %>
      <%= error_tag f, :name %>

      <%= label f, :quantity %>
      <%= number_input f, :quantity %>
      <%= error_tag f, :quantity %>

      <%= label f, :price %>
      <%= number_input f, :price %>
      <%= error_tag f, :price %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= select f, :category_id, @categories %>
        <p class="help is-danger"><%= error_tag f, :category %></p>
      </div>


      <%= label f, :subcategory %>
      <%= number_input f, :subcategory %>
      <%= error_tag f, :subcategory %>

      <%= label f, :description %>
      <%= text_input f, :description %>
      <%= error_tag f, :description %>

      <%= label f, :avdate %>
      <%= date_select f, :avdate %>
      <%= error_tag f, :avdate %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label f, :prodimg, class: "control-label" %>
        <%= file_input f, :prodimg, class: "form-control" %>
        <%= error_tag f, :prodimg %>
      </div>


      <div>
        <%= submit "Save" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the error pops up when you do a `create` or `update` that fails?

Solution: When you render the form with errors, don't forget to fetch and assign `categories`:

```
  def create(conn, %{"product" => product_params}) do
    case Inventory.create_product(product_params) do
      {:ok, product} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Product created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: Routes.product_path(conn, :show, product))

      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset} ->
        categories = Repo.all(Category) |> Enum.map(&{&1.name, &1.id}) # <- ADD THIS
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, categories: categories)
    end
  end
```

Same for the `update` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think it works because now I can add/edit product but only without the picture. When I try to add/edit a product with an image I see "Is invalid" under choose file button. In the console i am getting this message: 
[error] {:error, ["Invalid Parameter - /plug-1591\r\n", "Invalid Parameter - /plug-1591\r\n"]}
[debug] QUERY OK source="categories" db=0.0ms idle=532.0ms
SELECT c0."id", c0."name", c0."subcategory", c0."inserted_at", c0."updated_at" FROM "categories" AS c0 [] I guess it's something with my uploader but I totally don't understand this message.

Comment: You could write a controller plug, that loads the categories dependng on the route. All you will have to do in the plug is to fetch the categories and put in the assign map, futhermore you write a plug: `plug plug_name when action in [:new, :create]`.